# Should I modify CMAKE_MODULE_PATH in PackageConfig.cmake

Tags: cmake

I am writing a MyPackageConfig file for my project with exported targets so that other projects can easily find MyPackage and it's dependencies. It looks like this:

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)

find_dependency(LIB1_WITHOUT_CMAKE_CONFIG)
find_dependency(LIB2_WITH_CMAKE_CONFIG)

include (Some/Install/Dir/MyPackageTargets.cmake)
```

I am wondering if it is smart to add the following lines to the MyPackageConfig.cmake before the find_dependency calls

```
# Find target dependencies
# Allows packages linking with MyPackage to use the find modules that
# MyPackage used to find it's dependencies. Since this path is appended to
# the existing module path, the calling package's module path will take
# precedence

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH @CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@/lib/cmake/MyPackage/modules)

# Allows packages linking with MyPackage to find MyPacakge's dependencies if
# they don't already have them. Since this path (or these paths) are
# appended to the existing prefix path, the calling package's prefix
# path will take precedence

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH @CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH@)

find_dependency(LIB1_WITHOUT_CMAKE_CONFIG)
find_dependency(LIB2_WITH_CMAKE_CONFIG)
```

Good idea? No?

Longer explanation of my rationale:

1. How does YourPackage that uses MyPackage find LIB1?

   (i). You could write your own FindLIB1.cmake but that's duplication of effort

   (ii). I could install my FindLIB1.cmake alongside my MyPackageConfig.cmake in a Modules dir. But you will have to include this path in your module path.

   My suggestion: Add a line before `find_dependency(LIB1_WITHOUT_CMAKE_CONFIG)` modifying the module path like so:

```
  list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH  @CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@/lib/cmake/mstk/modules)
```

This will ensure that if you have a FindLIB1.cmake, it will be used but if you don't mine will be found and used.

2. How do you know where the LIB1 and LIB2 reside (including LIB2's Config file)?

   By adding the line

```
 list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH @CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH@)
```

I tell your package where I searched and found my dependencies (but only if you didn't already have them in the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH you specified)

Comment: Using "**host**"  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH for your config script via `@CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH@` has a little sense: When **building** your project the variable refers to location(s) on the **host** machine. But your script is used on the **target** machine (where someone *installs* your project). On *target* machine *host* paths are meaningless. Probably, you mean `@CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@` instead? (Which refers to the installation prefix on the *target* machine).

Comment: @Tsyvarev if you are building up dependencies aren't the host and target machine the same? I think it is unlikely that someone will move the installation from one machine to another.

Comment: You create the config script at the *build* time, so that creation uses **host** variables. Then this script is installed and can be copied to the *target* machine. If you want to use variables from the target, use them via `${XXX}`, not via `@XXX@`.

Comment: I realize now that instead of doing ```list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH @CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@/lib/cmake/MyPackage/modules)``` I can do ```list(PREPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH @CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR@/modules)``` - @Tsyvarev hints at this in his answer. The new way allows one to relocate the entire contents of the directory where the PkgConfig file is found (including the Targets file and modules directory) without breaking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may change variables like `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` or `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` for the purpose of your config script.

Any "good" project should be prepared to prepending/appending `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, because this variable could normally be set by a user (when call `cmake`). As for `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, module's names in different directories are rarely conflicted.

Some hints:

1. You may **restore** the variables at the end of your script. Such way you won't affect the calling code when changing the variables:

   ```
   # Store old value of the variable
   set(old_CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
   # Change variable, use it, ...
   # ...
   # Restore the variable at the end
   set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${old_CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
   ```

   Note, however, that `find_dependency` returns from the script if an (inner) package not found, so restoring the variable won't trigger in that case. But usually `find_package()` is called with *REQUIRED* keyword, so failing to find the inner package would be fatal.
2. Instead of changing `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` you may set **other variables** which affect only specific find script and doesn't affect others. E.g many find scripts use `XXX_ROOT` variables for hint about location.

   For find config script itself, you may use *PATHS* or *HINTS* options of `find_package()`:

   ```
   # Was:
   #- list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH @CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH@)
   #- find_dependency(LIB2_WITH_CMAKE_CONFIG)
   # Replace with:
   find_dependency(LIB2_WITH_CMAKE_CONFIG
       PATHS @CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH@ # Where to find config script
       NO_DEFAULT_PATH # Do not search other places
   )
   ```